# Combining multiple files in grunt-requirejs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have a Javascript application spanning multiple files using RequireJS, which I want to concatenate into one for the production environment.

I've been looking at [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) but the instructions for setting up the configuration in `Gruntfile.js` assume that you already have the concatenated, production source. I'm aware that I could also use `grunt-contrib-concat` for this, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it with the `grunt-contrib-requirejs` module.

I've also tried using a wildcard selection for the `name` field in the configuration, but although Grunt works fine with specifications like `app/**/*.js` `grunt-contrib-requirejs` doesn't concatenate them when I specify this.

I found [this example](https://github.com/robdodson/requirejs-multipage-shim-boilerplate/blob/master/options.js) on how to do this, but when I include multiple entries in the `modules` array, running Grunt complains that certain files can't load their dependencies that are specified in the main file's `require.config`.

For example, if this is `main.js`:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'angular': 'http://some.cdn/angular.min'
  },
  shim: {
    angular: {
      exports: 'angular'
    }
  }
});

//Set up basic code
```

And this is `controllers/ctrl.js`:

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
  ...
});
```

Then it's apparently not loading the configuration from `main.js` and complains that there's no file `/my/project/controllers/angular.js`

I've also tried moving the configuration to a file specified with the `mainConfigFile` option, but [this option does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415369/grunt-requirejs-ignores-paths-from-my-mainconfigfile) and it seems that this option was meant to take the Grunt configuration and not the RequireJS configuration.

Comment: You've looked at the [sample r.js example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js)?

Comment: @steveax Thanks for pointing me to that. I still cannot get grunt-requirejs to build what I want, though. I'm trying to get it to take a directory of files and combine them into a minified, output file. I'm setting the `paths` property to load third-party libraries from a CDN, as well as other local modules. When I specify `appDir` I get an error that it's looking for a file like `undefinedcontrollers/foo-ctrl.js` If I set a baseUrl, it looks for everything included CDN-hosted libraries relative to that path (e.g. `/my/dir/http://some.cdn/angular` Do you know of any instructions on this?